# Chrome Extension Redirection

Tags: google-chrome, redirect

Hi i did a Chrome extension who block urls, actually when a url is blocked a white page come and show a messagen i would like to do a redirection instead to google.com.

this is my actual code of background.js:

```html
(function() {
var AUTHORIZED_DOMAINS= {
"www.badurl.com": false,
"badurl.com": false
};
function extract_domain(url)    {
    var matches = url.match(/^https?\:\/\/([^\/?#]+)(?:[\/?#]|$)/i);
    return matches[1];
}
 
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) { 
var domain = extract_domain(details.url);
return { cancel: AUTHORIZED_DOMAINS[domain ]===false }; 
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},["blocking"]);})();
```

Comment: What is your error or your question? StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site.

Comment: my question is how to mak a redirection instead of an error message!

Answer (score 0):

instead of returning `{ cancel: ... }` in the listener, let's just use the [tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update):

`chrome.tabs.update({
     url: "http://www.google.com/"
});`

Note: **tabs** permission is required

Comment: i tried to replace: return { cancel: AUTHORIZED_DOMAINS[domain ]===false };    by return { chrome.tabs.update({
     url: "http://www.google.com/"
});   but its not working !!